# List of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
lista = [('ab','tall',3),
('go','cd',2),
('gb','my',1),
('game','me', 2),
('uk','try',4),
('me','hello',1),
('good','try',3)]
```

I need to extract all those elements which have 3rd value of tuple less than 3 and then check if they are next to each other.

Required output

`('go','cd',2)`, `('gb','my',1)`, `('game','me', 2)` and `('me','hello',1)`
and then check which are next to each other which in this case is `('go','cd',2)`, `('gb','my',1)`, `('game','me', 2)` are next to each other.

Comment: Why is the 4th element not 'next to' the 3rd?

Comment: So you want the first contiguous group where all values in the 3rd column are below 3? What happens if there is another tuple next to `('me', 'hello', 1)` that would make that a group of length 2 or longer?

Comment: yup i want contiguous group. if there is another tuple next to ('me', 'hello',1) then there would be 2 different groups..As long as group size is greater than 1

Comment: I still don't get it. The sample output you give is *not* contiguous in the third element of each tuple. `2 > 1`.

Comment: @Sb92: Not getting the second part?  Have you try some cod for that?

Comment: @Sb92 Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29511046/edit). Don't put code into a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by "next to each other" but I tried to guess. It is necessary to add a condition checking special cases like `len(lista) < 2`.

Also `is_valid` list is not necessary and you can move the condition into the loop, but I find this more understandable.

```
lista = [('ab','tall',3),
('go','cd',2),
('gb','my',1),
('game','me', 2),
('uk','try',4),
('me','hello',1),
('good','try',3)]

# items that fullfill the condition
is_valid = [1 if item[2] < 3 else 0 for item in lista]

# handling "next to each other condition" of the first item
valid_items = []
if is_valid[0] == 1 and is_valid[1]:
    valid_items.append(lista[0]) 

# handling "next to each other condition" of items that are not the first and not the last      
for item_id in range(1, len(is_valid)-1):
    if is_valid[item_id] == 1 and (is_valid[item_id - 1] == 1 or is_valid[item_id + 1] == 1):
        valid_items.append(lista[item_id])
# handling "next to each other condition" of the last item in the list
if is_valid[-2] == 1 and is_valid[-1] == 1:
    valid_items.append(lista[-1])

# just print the result
print valid_items
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Part:**

Extract all those elements which have 3rd value of tuple less than 3.

By list comprehension.

code:

```
>>> lista = [('ab','tall',3),
... ('go','cd',2),
... ('gb','my',1),
... ('game','me', 2),
... ('uk','try',4),
... ('me','hello',1),
... ('good','try',3)]
>>> [i for i in lista if i[2] < 3]
[('go', 'cd', 2), ('gb', 'my', 1), ('game', 'me', 2), ('me', 'hello', 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: And now the second part :)